# plotly scattermapbox location pin examples | How to add location pin in scattermapbox

Tags: python, google-maps, maps, scatter-plot

I am using scattermapbox and I am using marker -> circle, I need to use location pin as shown in google maps. can you provide an example of what symbol should be used.

```
fig = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(
        lat=df["Latitude"],
        lon=df["Longitude"],
        mode='markers',
        marker=go.scattermapbox.Marker(
            size=10,
            color =  df['Size'],
            colorscale = scl# This is used to match the color scale
        ),
    ))
```